# Select text content between elements

Tags: php, character, explode

How can I select the content between elements in text? For example, in this text I want to select the content between *[* and *]*:

> Hello everybody [ I want to select only this section, nothing more ]. Hi. How are you? zzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz

**If I have this text inside text I can use:**

```
<?php
 $a=file("text.txt");
 print "".$a[]."";
?>
```

And I can use `explode`, but the problem is that explode doesn’t work for two or mor characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for you

```
<?php

$s = 'Helo [everybody] [Only i need this select no more], hi [how] are you zzzzzz';

if (preg_match_all("^\[(.*?)\]^", $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
       echo $match[0]."<br/>";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get content between [] use this regular expression: '[(.*)]'

Sample Code:

```
$var = "Helo everybody [ Only i need this select no more ] , hi how are you zzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz";

$matches = array();
$t = preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\]/s', $var, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[Eval](https://eval.in/46276)

Comment: If i have more text with more [] inside ?

Comment: In that case, just change preg_match to preg_match_all

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "Hello everybody [ I want to select only this section, nothing more ]. Hi. How are you? zzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz";
$from = "[";
$to = "]";

echo getBetween($str,$from,$to);

function getBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
    return substr(substr($str,strpos($str,$from),strlen($str)),1,strpos(substr($str,strpos($str,$from),strlen($str)),$to)-1);
}
?>
```